# How to connect to webService on my PC from PPC - but this PC not connect to network?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

How to connect to webService on my PC from PPC  - but this PC not connect to network ?

(the PPC is connected to the PC through ActiveSync)

thank's in advance

Comment: Just to clarify -- you want to connect to a PC which is not connected to the network? In that case magic fairy dust does seem quite appropiate. :)

Comment: no fairy dust needed - just the USB cable.  This is not an unreasonable request.

Answer (score 4):

If the device is connected to the PC via ActiveSync or WMDC, then you *do* have a network.  Use "ppp-peer" as the network name to resolve the IP.